# Proving absolute continuity/uniform continuity of $-\log^{-1}(x)$

Tags: uniform-continuity, absolute-continuity

My question is how to prove that the function
$$
f(x)=-\log^{-1}(x)
$$
for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$ on $[0,1/2]$ is absolutely continuous/uniform continuous.

I feel like both proofs would be similar, but I am having a hard time bounding
$$
|f(a)-f(b)| = \left|\frac{\log(a/b)}{\log(a)\log(b)}\right|.
$$
I think I am missing some obvious inequality and cannot seem to crack it. Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Uniform continuity follows from the fact that $f$ is a continuous function on a closed interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$, we have that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^{2}}.$
We go to verify that $f(x)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt$ for each $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}].$
Once it is proved, $f$ is absolutely continuous because it is a function defined by an integral.

Fix $x\in(0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Note that $f'\geq0$. By Monotone Convergence
Theorem, we have that $\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{x}1_{[\frac{1}{n},x]}(t)f'(t)dt$.
However, since $f'$ is continuous on $[\frac{1}{n},x]$, by the classical
Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{x}1_{[\frac{1}{n},x]}(t)f'(t)dt\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{x}f'(t)dt\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(x)-f(\frac{1}{n})\right]\\
 & = & f(x)-f(0).
\end{eqnarray*}